# What material should I use for a platform that holds 300-500 lbs?

Tags: installation, metal, support

I am making a flat platform with 4 leveling feet that can hold a [150 lb Corrosion-Resistant Heavy Duty Blower](http://www.mcmaster.com/#catalog/119/664/=n2513p) plus another 150-350 lb (so in total 300 - 500 lbs of mass). It is around 24" x 24". Do you guys have any suggestions on what material I should use and how thick?

Also if I wanted to reduce the vibration from the fan would it be a good ideal to put a layer of rubber on the platform?

This will be indoors and will be a raised platform, I was thinking of using [Heavy Duty Vibration-Damping Leveling Mounts](http://www.mcmaster.com/#adjustable-feet/=n1zbjy.)

Comment: What sort of fan is that and how big is it? that's a huge fan.

Comment: Sorry, it is around a 150 lb "Corrosion-Resistant Heavy Duty Blowers" found here: http://www.mcmaster.com/#catalog/119/664/=n1w1wo. But with all the components on the platform the total weight comes to around 300 - 500 lbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

300-500 lbs is not really *THAT* much, spread over 4 square feet. That's the weight of about 2 people. Your question is a little vague since you don't say whether this is for indoors or outdoors, whether this is a raised wood platform like a deck, or a concrete pad, or what.

If you want to use wood, you could definitely just use 2x's like for a deck. If it's not that high, you could put it on 4x4 posts and that would be plenty strong enough. You could attach your leveling feet under the posts.

To reduce vibration you could use rubber, although whatever you do you should make sure that the fan is properly secured. You can get round rubber cups that go under washing machines to reduce vibrations: that might be one way to go.

Comment: This will be indoors and will be a raised platform, I was thinking of using these adjustable mounts: http://www.mcmaster.com/#adjustable-feet/=n1zbjy. Just curious, why would indoor or outdoor affect the plate choice? Thanks for the suggestion in using wood, is this alternative cheaper than using steel for example?

Comment: If it were outdoors you would need to make sure it's properly attached to the ground so it doesn't blow over in a storm, or get water damage, or something. As for wood / steel, it's your choice really. I like wood because it's pretty cheap, very easy to work with, and you could get a large flat surface that would be easy to attach things to. But you could also easily get some angle iron and bolt it together, if you're looking for something a little more industrial-strength.

Comment: What kind of wood do you suggest using? Would be awesome if I could buy it from http://www.mcmaster.com/ unless they don't sell it.

Comment: One more thing, what are "2x's"? Another place I could purchase it from would be home depot store which is very close to where I live.

Comment: In the US, wood sold for construction comes in standard sizes, e.g. 2x4, 2x6, 2x8 (a.k.a. "2x's"). Those are the cross sections and are nominal dimensions.  The actual cross section of a 2x4 is 1.5" x 3.5". You can buy them in various lengths, usually 6', 8', 12'. I don't know whether you can buy wood online; I would go to Home Depot. For vertical posts, square pieces are often used, e.g. 4x4 (3.5" x 3.5" cross section).

Comment: Ah, okay, so kind of like this: http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/242137039/wooden_deck.jpg? Which means I need to attach them to each other by using adhesives or some mechanical components?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wide range of materials to build the platform. Part of the selection process will be guided by the usage model of the platform, indoors or outdoors, portable of fixed, high or low from floor or ground and maybe some others.

Vibration isolation of the fan unit will be far better addressed by how you mount the fan to the platform as opposed to just covering the surface of the platform with a sheet of rubber. So if the fan/blower unit has a mounting point like this:

[image]

Then you would want to consider mounting on isolation mounts similar to these components:

[Bolt-Down Vibration-Damping Mounts](http://www.mcmaster.com/#standard-vibration-damping-mounts/=n1yg61)

[image]

[Vibration-Damping Sandwich Mounts](http://www.mcmaster.com/#vibration-damping-sandwich-mounts/=n1yijk)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using these adjustable mounts: http://www.mcmaster.com/#adjustable-feet/=n1zbjy. I need to be able to make slight adjustments in height for the entire platform.